# My LWC comes up as Object object in communities but works in lightning apps page

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have created this custom LWC to bring back some data from a custom object but for some reason when I return the data in a Community page I get:

[image]

When its a lightning component on a home page it comes back as:

[image]

any idea what im doing wrong?

apex cont:

```
public with sharing class rentController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<ac_housmng__Tenancy__c> getRent() {
        user contactId;
        String userID = '0052z000002exZjAAI';

        ContactId = [SELECT ContactID FROM User WHERE Id = :userID LIMIT 1];

        return [SELECT ac_housmng__Tenant_Balance__c, ac_housmng__Rent_Amount__c FROM ac_housmng__Tenancy__c WHERE ac_housmng__Tenant__c = :ContactId.contactId];
    }
}
```

JS :

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getRent from '@salesforce/apex/rentController.getRent';
export default class LwcCurrentUserInfo extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getRent) rent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<lightning-card title="Property Rent">
    <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
        <template if:true={rent.data}>

            <template for:each={rent.data} for:item="user">

                <h1 key={user.ac_housmng__Tenant_Balance__c}>Balance</h1>
                <h2 key={user.ac_housmng__Tenant_Balance__c}>{user.ac_housmng__Tenant_Balance__c}</h2>
                <br key={user.ac_housmng__Tenant_Balance__c} />

                <h1 key={user.ac_housmng__Rent_Amount__c}>Rent Cost</h1>
                <h2 key={user.ac_housmng__Rent_Amount__c}><lightning-formatted-number value={user.ac_housmng__Rent_Amount__c} maximum-fraction-digits="2"></lightning-formatted-number></h2>
                <br key={user.ac_housmng__Rent_Amount__c} />
            </template>
        </template>

        <template if:true={rent.error}>
            {rent.error}
        </template>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

Comment: Make sure you provided Apex class `rentController` access to the user profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should debug what you have in `rent.error` when it is opened in the community.

It seems like, there is some exception thrown by `rentController.getRent` method, which is an object in `error`. `[object Object]` is exactly how LWC framework renders on page js objects.

---

Add debug log trace for a user, which is opening it in the community and there might be some exception thrown.

Use `wire` decorator for function and log the error and check it from the browser console

```
export default class LwcCurrentUserInfo extends LightningElement {
    rent;
    @wire(getRent)
    wiredRent(response) {
        this.rent = response;
        if (response.error) {
            console.error('Rent error: ', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.error)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this actually solved my problem I'm very new to apex and it turns out the apex wasn't enabled for the community profile all working now cheers!